# Listview. Load image from file

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to load image in first column (detail view) Listview from a file instead from ImageList's and how?

```
                Dim lvi As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem("Row1")
                With .Items.Add("0") '' PICTURE HERE IF POSSIBLE
                    .SubItems.Add("User name")
                    .SubItems.Add("Unactive")
                End With
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would have to make a imagelist "on the fly".

Something on the lines of:-

```
    Dim ImageList As New ImageList

    Dim Lvi As New ListViewItem()
        ImageList.Images.Add(PictureBox1.Image, Color.White)
    With Lvi
        .Text = "Blah..."
        .ImageIndex = 0
    End With
    ListView1.Items.Add(Lvi)
```

(NOTE: Didnt test the code, just wrote it off the top of my head.)